# MongoDB Compatibility java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, mongo-java-driver

Given this table: https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#reference-compatibility-mongodb-java

Seems like java driver `2.13.3` is not compatible with `MongoDB 3.4`

Nevertheless I'm working on a project with java driver `2.13.3` and using the `MongoDB 3.4 server` and I'm not having any trouble.

Obviously to have the latest version is recommended but as usual it needs a lot of re-work (deprecated methods, new properties, etc.), so the decision is not easy.

What are the points that my team should take into account in deciding whether to upgrade to the latest driver version?

Comment: It's a bit broad of an ask really. Any 2,x series driver is not really a major problem, but of course there are newer features ( notably Decimal128 BSON Type ) that are really only available in latest driver releases. So that's the only real deal breaker that I'm aware of with any serious impact if you want to use the new addition to the wire protocol. As for the rest it kind of becomes subjective. Things like `Document` are preferred over `DBObject`, but the latter is not really considered deprecated. And that's actually a lot more consistent with other API Changes.

Comment: In all honesty the big things to worry about would be more along the lines of if any of the codebase used `DBRef`, then start migrating away from that. Or similarly if there is anything using serverside JavaScript through `eval()`, then that has a more pressing deprecation on the server. So there really is not that many things that stop older API from working with newer server. Most things strive to be backwards compatible, and most of the API changes are actually just reworkings, and not really breaking changes.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It is a broad question. Anyway, I appreciate your response, we will start migrating but I don't find any big break as you mentioned so we can migrate slowly when our backlog allows it.

Comment: Here are general guidelines http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/whats-new/upgrading/